# Any event to detect when the "Class" attribute is changed for a control

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, javascript-framework, jquery-events

I have a "div" control with some `id="myDiv" class="myClass"
var var1=10;`
in Javascript. Based on user  action I will change the class for this control from "myClass" to "newClass" so when this has happened I want to change the value of var1 to 20.

So how would I recognize that change in Class?

Comment: why can't you change the value while you change the class?

Comment: changing the class is done in Jquery plugin so i dont want to make changes there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [onpropertychange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536956%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)(IE) and [DOMAttrModified](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMAttrModified) (others)

Comment: What did not help? You'll find an example how to use is at http://help.dottoro.com/ljdchxcl.php , and it works.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to use 3 things:

1. **onpropertychange** event, for IE < 9
2. **DOMAttrModified**, works in IE9, Opera, Firefox, and not regrettably in all **others** as  Dr.Molle suggests
3. Everything else - must resort to **setInterval loop**, that checks if value changed, this includes webkit browsers (chrome and safari), since they still don't have DOMAttrModified support, so  - you'll have to resort to loop check for those browsers.

There is jQuery plugin which implements this (there is also a demo on the page):

http://darcyclarke.me/dev/watch/