# Detecting change in hidden form field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im writing a test code to do a counter that stores the value in a hidden form field. Whenever this counter is incremented with a button click, the counter value is stored in the hidden field. I have no problem with this portion.

However, im having problem to display an alert whenever the hidden field is being changed. Pls see my code below and tell me where i have gone wrong. Thank You.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function startRolling() {
            var storage=document.getElementById('store').value;  

            var tonum;

            if(parseInt(storage)==0)
                {
                    tonum=1;

                }
             else {
                 tonum=parseInt(storage,10);

             }

            tonum=tonum+1;
            document.getElementById('store').value=tonum;
            storage=document.getElementById('store').value;
            alert(storage)
        }


        $(document).ready(function() {
var content = $('#store').val();

$('#store').change(function() { 
    if ($('#store').val() != content) {

        alert('Content has been changed')
    }
});
```

});

```
    </script>


</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="trigger" value="Start" onclick="startRolling()"/>
    <input type="text" id="cnt" readonly="readonly"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="store" value="0"/>
</body>
```

Comment: If they're going so far as to manually edit a *hidden* form field, what makes you think they couldn't easily just delete that snippet of code so it doesn't check?

Comment: This code is just a smaller portion of a bigger program that im developing. The actual program wont be published on the internet but just on the localhost to achieve a one-time routine task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you just fire the event without trying to detect the change?

```
function startRolling() {
        var storage=document.getElementById('store').value;  

        var tonum;

        if(parseInt(storage)==0)
            {
                tonum=1;

            }
         else {
             tonum=parseInt(storage,10);

         }

        tonum=tonum+1;
        document.getElementById('store').value=tonum;
        if(storage != tonum) {
             alertChange();
        }
        //storage=document.getElementById('store').value;
        //alert(storage)
}

function alertChange() {
        alert('Content has been changed');
}
```

You could also look at the trigger event in jquery: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/.

Comment: I think I have wasted too much time on what is supposed to be a simple solution. I'm away from my PC now but I think this should work fine. I will test this out and post my solution. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function startRolling() {
        var storage=document.getElementById('store').value;  

        var tonum;

        if(parseInt(storage)==0)
            {
                tonum=1;

            }
         else {
             tonum=parseInt(storage,10);

         }

        tonum=tonum+1;
        document.getElementById('store').value=tonum;
        //storage=document.getElementById('store').value;
        //alert(storage)
}


    $(document).ready(function() {
        //var content = $('#store').val();

        $('#store').change(function() { 
        //if ($('#store').val() != content) {

            alert('Content has been changed')
        }
    });
```

Why don't you change the first function to jquery?

Comment: Tried that, still doesn't fires the alert. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**From the [description of the change-event](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents):**
*The change event occurs when a control loses the input focus and its value has been modified since gaining focus.*

Hidden inputs cannot lose focus(because they never have focus), so change will not fire there anyway.

See [Any even to detect when the "Class" attribute is changed for a control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904648/any-even-to-detect-when-the-class-attribute-is-changed-for-a-control/5904710#5904710) for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a change event, I've used a loop event that checks every second.

```
var content="";
        function startRolling() {
            var storage=document.getElementById('store').value;  

            var tonum;

            if(parseInt(storage)==0)
                {
                    tonum=1;

                }
             else {
                 tonum=parseInt(storage,10);

             }

            tonum=tonum+1;
            document.getElementById('store').value=tonum;  
            storage=document.getElementById('store').value;
            content=storage;
            alert(storage)
        }

function checkifchanged(){
     if ($('#store').val() != content) {
alert('Content has been changed');
    }
    else{
      content = $('#store').val();   
    }
    setTimeout('checkifchanged()',1000);
}
        $(document).ready(function() {
           content = $('#store').val();   
checkifchanged();
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var content = $('#store').val();
```

You are storing the changed value and comparing with the same value,
this if statement doesn't execute

```
if ($('#store').val() != content)
```

don't store the value just call change event directly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#store').change(function() { 
        alert('Content has been changed')
});
```