# Detecting if height of DIV changes

Tags: javascript

Using `document.getElementByID('div1').clientHeight` How can I detect if div1's height changes?

I need to make an operation if the condition (Div1's height change) satisfies.

E.g.

```
if(document.getElementByID('div1').clientHeight != //old div1's height)
{
   // do my operation
}
```

Can anybody please provide me with the syntax of such JavaScript.

Comment: In what scenarios does the height of the DIV change? Are you manipulating its content? If yes, just trigger the operation whenever you change its content.

Comment: Also a `window.resize` can change the height of DIVs

Comment: Yeah! Height of div1 changes dynamically as new data is going to be added to it.

Comment: there is an `onresize` event for divs.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904648/any-even-to-detect-when-the-class-attribute-is-changed-for-a-control/5904710#5904710

Comment: @Oliver The `resize` event doesn't fire at DIVs...

Comment: Still no solution yet?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053583/jquery-resize-listener-on-a-div

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the style property of the div. maybe your old div1's height is 20px;

```
if(document.getElementByID('div1').style.height != 20px;)
{
   // do my operation
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use JQuery like so

```
$(elm).resize(function(event) {
    alert('resized!');
    /* ... other code ... */
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/resize/ for more information.

Independent of any implementation you should probably use a throttler: "Code in a resize handler should never rely on the number of times the handler is called. Depending on implementation, resize events can be sent continuously as the resizing is in progress (the typical behavior in Internet Explorer and WebKit-based browsers such as Safari and Chrome), or only once at the end of the resize operation (the typical behavior in some other browsers such as Opera)."

Comment: btw, jquery was not tagged. :)

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Ah, you seem to be correct. Still, you could fire the "resize" event manually, for example based on a click or keyup.

Comment: @WillemMulder You don't need the `resize` event as a proxy. The OP can just execute the operation directly whenever he manipulates the contents of the DIV.

Comment: Of course, but it is always good to make it event based so you can create multiple hooks at the resize.

Answer (score -1):

```
document.getElementById('div1').onresize = function() {...};
```

Put whatever code you want in the function.

I'm not 100% certain this'll work. You may be better off having a `setInterval` which checks if the `offsetHeight` has changed and acts accordingly.